# Egyptian fractions inequality problem

Tags: inequality, egyptian-fractions

If $\frac{a}{b}$ is a non-unit fraction between 0 and 1, in lowest terms let $\frac{1}{n}$ be the largest unit fraction less than $\frac{a}{b}$, and form the fraction $\frac{a^{'}}{b^{'}}=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{n}$. Assume $\frac{a^{'}}{b^{'}}$ is in lowest terms, show that $0<a^{'}<a$.

Progress so far:

Since $\frac{a^{'}}{b^{'}}=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{n}\Rightarrow\frac{a^{'}}{b^{'}}<\frac{a}{b}$

I managed to show that if $\frac{a^{'}}{b^{'}}$ is a unit fraction, $0<a^{'}<a$, as it is stated that $\frac{1}{n}$ is the largest unit fraction.

I can't find a way to show that $0<a^{'}<a$ when $\frac{a^{'}}{b^{'}}$ is a non-unit fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{n}>0$, but $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{n-1}<0$. What do you see when you clear denominators?

Further hint: Note $\frac{a'}{b'}=\frac{an-b}{bn}$. So $a'\leq an-b$ (why?).

Comment: I got the inequality $a(n-1)<b<an$, but I don't see how this leads to determining $a^{'}<a$.

Comment: @shredalert I have added another hint.

Comment: I previously figured out that $a^{'}=an-b$ and $b^{'}=bn$. I don't understand when $a^{'}<an-b$ applies and how it relates to my overall aim.

Comment: You needn't have $a'=an-b,b'=bn$, since $(an-b)/bn$ might not be a reduced fraction. But after you put this fraction into the reduced form, numerator, which now will be $a'$, couldn't have increased, so $a'\leq an-b$. Now it's enough to show $an-b<a$.

Comment: So $(an-b)/bn$ might not be a reduced fraction, but after we do reduce it and take $a^{'}$ as the numerator using the equation $a^{'}/b^{'}=an-b/bn$, $a^{'}\le an-b$ because it is in reduced form and the value of $a^{'}$ can't increase. Using the inequality $a(n-1)<b<an$ we can also show $an-b<a$; this implies $a^{'}\le an-b<a$ which gives us $0<a^{'}<a$. I believe I understand now. Thank you.